# iPad orientation Problem

Tags: ipad

-(void) setOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation toOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    //toOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

```
if (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
{


}else if(toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
     || toOrientation  == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){


}
```

}

When i am going to move iPad in Landscape position from Portrait position, portrait condition is get executed. Due to this my screen is distorted.

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what your question is?

Comment: Just to help you delete some code, you can use this function : 

UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape (yourOrientation)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the interface being automatically reorganized to fit the other orientation, you should set a new frame to all interface elements when the screen gets rotated.